# Spring boot application JS and CSS not binding in standalone server(Apache Tomcat Version 9.0)

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring-boot, tomcat

```
<!-- own css location -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
<!-- own javascript location -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/login.js"></script>
```

this is how the i have given the link for my js and css.
it is working fine in spring boot internal server but if i convert to war and when i deployed it in apache tomcat 9.0 server it is returning 404 error, for the above mentioned resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `<base>` tag in index.html or specify  full path with server name and port.

Comment: Sorry <base> tag is not working for me after using also it i showing the same error.